# Angular dependcy injection of factory in factory returns empty object

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

So i have this really weird problem where i can't inject one factory into another, but only in one specific factory.

So i have the following code..

Controller:

```
angular.module('cheetah').controller("NewSprintController", ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$state", "EventService", "$modalInstance", "$timeout", "ErrorService", "NewSprintLogicService", "EventIdentifierService", function NewSprintController($rootScope, $scope, $state, evs, $modalInstance, $timeout, err, nsl, eis) {
    $scope.Sprint = nsl.CreateSprint();
    ...
```

Where i inject my `NewSprintLogicService`, which i resolve as `nsl`. This works just fine, if we then look at the `NewSprintLogicService`, it looks like this:

```
angular.module("cheetah").factory("NewSprintLogicService", ["ApiService", function NewSprintLogicService(api) {
return {
    CreateSprint: function () { return api.Sprint(); },
    GetAll: function() {
    ...
```

Now, here i'm injecting my ApiService, and this is where it gets tricky. I'm getting an empty object injected. This pattern works fine with a different controller and logic service. The Sprint property is actually defined in the `ApiService`.

And just clarify, here is my ApiService:

```
angular.module("cheetah").factory("ApiService", ["$resource", function ApiService($resource) {
return {
    UserStory: $resource("/api/UserStory/:userStoryId", { userStoryId: "@Id" }),
    ...
```

I'm not getting any errors, besides a "cannot read property from undefined" and "undefined is not a function", when trying to use the ApiService in the LogicService.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it helps to try and formulate problems as a Stackoverflow question. In this case it has dawned on me that i was missing a "new" in my LogicService, so it should be like this instead:

```
angular.module("cheetah").factory("NewSprintLogicService", ["ApiService", function NewSprintLogicService(api) {
return {
    CreateSprint: function () { return new api.Sprint(); },
    ...
```

Simple mistake.